# Sort a directory​ then find a file on lastwritetime in that dir

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with lots of sub-directories which in turn have files.
The file I'm looking for mostly is in the latest modified sub-directory.

This setup is on UNC.

To find the file as quickly as possible I want to first sort the sub-directory on last modified time and then search.

1. `Get-ChildItem | Sort lastwritetime -Descending`
2. `Get-ChildItem filename.txt -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt "MM/dd/yyyy" -and $_.lastwritetime -lt "MM/dd/yyyy"}`

I want to pass the output of 1 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1
```

will get the most recent file, you can change `-Last` for `-First` to get the oldest unmodified file.

you can also specify `-File` or `-Directory` on `Get-ChildItem` to make sure you get only files/dirs.

edit: after your question update.

```
$SearchIn = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1
Get-ChildItem $SearchIn.FullName -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt "MM/dd/yyyy" -and $_.lastwritetime -lt "MM/dd/yyyy"}
```